# Making a PHP Button Clickable

Tags: php, wordpress, html-object

Firstly, thanks so much for your help.

I am creating a Wordpress site for a client which you can see here: http://christchurchhelicopters.co.nz/new

Essentially, for user experience, we want to make each of the tours clickable (as in the image as well). This is because at the moment, all that's clickable is the title, which isn't obvious.

I found the code where it's all stored, but can't work out a way to put the link to the tour URL into the href tags.

Code:

```
<?php
/**
* @package  WordPress
* @subpackage   Travel Time
* @version      1.0.0
* 
* Posts Slider Standard Tour Format Template
* Created by CMSMasters
* 
*/


$cmsmasters_metadata = explode(',', $cmsmasters_project_metadata);

$title = (in_array('title', $cmsmasters_metadata)) ? true : false;
$excerpt = (in_array('excerpt', $cmsmasters_metadata) && travel_time_project_check_exc_cont()) ? true : false;
$categories = (get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'pj-categs') && (in_array('categories', $cmsmasters_metadata))) ? true : false;
$comments = (comments_open() && (in_array('comments', $cmsmasters_metadata))) ? true : false;
$likes = (in_array('likes', $cmsmasters_metadata)) ? true : false;
$icon = in_array('icon', $cmsmasters_metadata) ? true : false;
$duration = in_array('duration', $cmsmasters_metadata) ? true : false;
$participants = in_array('participants', $cmsmasters_metadata) ? true : false;
$price = in_array('price', $cmsmasters_metadata) ? true : false;
$rating = in_array('rating', $cmsmasters_metadata) ? true : false;


$cmsmasters_project_icon = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_icon', true);
$cmsmasters_project_duration = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_duration', true);
$cmsmasters_project_participants = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_participants', true);
$cmsmasters_project_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_price', true);


$cmsmasters_project_link_url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_link_url', true);

$cmsmasters_project_link_redirect = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters_project_link_redirect', true);


?>

<!--_________________________ Start Standard Tour _________________________ -->

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('cmsmasters_slider_project'); ?>>
<div class="cmsmasters_slider_project_outer">
<div class="project_outer_image_wrap">

<?php 
if ($icon || $price || $categories || $title || $likes || $comments) {
echo '<div class="project_outer_image_wrap_meta entry-meta">';

$icon ? travel_time_project_icon($cmsmasters_project_icon) : '';

$price ? travel_time_project_price($cmsmasters_project_price, 'page') : '';

if ($categories || $title || $likes || $comments) {

echo '<div class="project_outer_image_wrap_meta_bottom entry-meta">';

$categories ?  travel_time_get_slider_post_category(get_the_ID(), 'pj-categs', 'project') : '';

$title ? travel_time_slider_post_heading(get_the_ID(), 'project', 'h2', $cmsmasters_project_link_redirect, $cmsmasters_project_link_url) : '';

$comments ? travel_time_get_slider_post_comments('project') : '';   

$likes ? travel_time_slider_post_like('project') : '';

echo '</div>';

}

echo '</div>';
}

travel_time_thumb_rollover(get_the_ID(), 'cmsmasters-tour-thumb', false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, $cmsmasters_project_link_redirect, $cmsmasters_project_link_url);

echo '</div>';

if ($excerpt || $duration || $participants || $rating ) {
echo '<div class="project_inner">';

$excerpt ? travel_time_slider_post_exc_cont('project') : '';

echo '<footer class="cmsmasters_project_footer entry-meta">';

$duration ? travel_time_project_duration($cmsmasters_project_duration, 'page') : '';

$participants ? travel_time_project_participants($cmsmasters_project_participants, 'page') : '';

if (CMSMASTERS_SIMPLE_RATING && $rating ) {
travel_time_simple_rating(get_the_ID(), 'page');
}

echo '</footer>';


echo '</div>';
}

?>
</div>
</article>
<!--_________________________ Finish Standard Tour _________________________ -->
```

Comment: It doesn't quite seem like this is all of the code. `travel_time_slider_post_heading()` seems to be creating a link on the `h2` using `$cmsmasters_project_link_url`. but I'm afraid I can't help you beyond that. Somehow you'd need to wrap the entire image area with the `$cmsmasters_project_link_url` var.

Comment: why not ask the authors: http://cmsmasters.net/support/

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys - I'll ask the authors if we can't sort it today, but it's just a timezone difference where I won't hear back from them for around 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading from mobile, so hope I'm not missing something on the code above, but seems that the function **travel_time_thumb_rollover** is responsible of printing the link. Try looking for it with a recursive full text search in your project folder.
Basically you should unwrap the `<a>` around the title to put it around the whole thumbnail.